# How open the keyboard on the list whith react-native

Tags: reactjs, listview, react-native, keyboard, chat

I'm trying to implement a chat in my application, but when I open the keyboard to start a conversation, the conversation is released from view.

When you do not open it can not be found to talk about the user's view. What exactly is the whatsapp application?

Here's my code and a gif of what's happening.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyExS.gif

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, ListView, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Container } from 'native-base';
import Conversation from '../services/conversation';
import Imagens from '../../../imagens';


class Chat extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      conversationHistory: [],
      mensagem: ''
    };
   }

  sendMessage(text) {

    Conversation.message({
      text
    }).then(r => {
      if (r != null && r !== undefined) {
        r.data_iteracao = new Date().getHours() + ':' + new Date().getMinutes();
        this.state.conversationHistory.push(r);
        this.setState({
          conversationHistory: this.state.conversationHistory
        });
      }
    });
  }

  renderRow(texto) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.item}>
        <View style={[{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }]}>
          <View style={[styles.balloon, { alignItems: 'flex-end', backgroundColor: '#dbf5b4', elevation: 1, padding: 5, borderRadius: 8 }]}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: '#000', }}>{texto.input.text}</Text>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: '#000' }}>{texto.data_iteracao}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={[{ alignItems: 'flex-start', borderRadius: 20 }]}>
          <View style={[styles.balloon, { alignItems: 'flex-start', backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7', elevation: 1, padding: 5, borderRadius: 8 }]}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 14, color: '#000' }}>{texto.output.text}</Text>
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end' }}>
              <Text style={{ fontSize: 10, color: '#000' }}>{texto.data_iteracao}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View >
      </View >
    );
  }

  render() {
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    return (

      <View style={styles.container}>

        <ListView
          enableEmptySections
          dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.conversationHistory)}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          renderScrollComponent={props => <ScrollView {...props} />}
          onEndReachedThreshold={10}
          ref={ref => this.listView = ref}
          onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
            this.listView.scrollToEnd({ animated: false });
          }} />


        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="digite a mensagem..."
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              value={this.state.mensagem}
              onChangeText={(mensagem) => this.setState({ mensagem })} />
          </View>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnSend} onPress={() => this.sendMessage(this.state.mensagem)}>
            <Image source={Imagens.send} style={styles.iconSend} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>

    );
  }

}

export default connect()(Chat);
```

Comment: try to wrap your root view with [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should add KeyboardAvoidingView to view:

```
return (

   <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <ListView
          enableEmptySections
          dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.conversationHistory)}
          renderRow={this.renderRow}
          renderScrollComponent={props => <ScrollView {...props} />}
          onEndReachedThreshold={10}
          ref={ref => this.listView = ref}
          onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
            this.listView.scrollToEnd({ animated: false });
          }} />


        <View style={styles.footer}>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput style={styles.inputs}
              placeholder="digite a mensagem..."
              underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
              value={this.state.mensagem}
              onChangeText={(mensagem) => this.setState({ mensagem })} />
          </View>

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnSend} onPress={() => this.sendMessage(this.state.mensagem)}>
            <Image source={Imagens.send} style={styles.iconSend} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
     </KeyboardAvoidingView>

    );
```